# C# rijndael CryptoStream can I write to file bits and bits like the way textwriter does?

Tags: c#, rijndaelmanaged

Was stuggling in how to encrypt 2 strings together.

Because I add bits and bits string in real time (by str = str + bitString;) and at the end. I generate the string and encrpt it.

Now the question is can I encypt and write the bitString in real time like textwriter?
Something like:
CrytoStream cr = new (outFile,xxx,write)
cr.write(bitString);

Examples would be appricated.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I follow. Are you asking if it is possible to write an encrypted file using a CryptoStream?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly what CryptoStream is designed to handle.

For a full sample, see [MSDN's Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx), in particular, the EncryptTextToFile method.

You just construct the CryptoStream "on top" of any FileStream (or any other stream), then write data directly to the cryptostream:

```
FileStream fStream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

// Create the CryptoStream
CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(fStream, Rijndael.Create().CreateEncryptor(Key, IV),                 CryptoStreamMode.Write);

// Create a StreamWriter using the CryptoStream.
StreamWriter sWriter = new StreamWriter(cStream);

// Write data to be encrypted:

sWriter.WriteLine("Some text that will get encrypted");
sWriter.WriteLine("More data...");
```